# How to make findbugs exclude @FXML methods from the "unused private method" warning?

Tags: java, javafx, findbugs

Findbugs will give a "Private method myMethod() is never called" warning for private methods, even though they're annotated with @FXML and used in the fxml files. That's understandable, it doesn't read the fxml files and can't know they are in use.  However, it's annoying me and I would like to exclude these methods from those warnings.

I do **not** want to:

- Make the methods public.
- Disable all warnings for unused private methods.
- Add every presenter in my projects to a filter that excludes this warning.
- Litter my presenters with @SuppressWarning annotations at every method with the @FXML annotation.

I **do want to:**

- Make findbugs automatically exclude any private method with the @FXML annotation from the "unused private method" warning.

I've read the findbugs documentation, but could not find how to make a match for annotations in filters or any other way to do this.  I've searched the web for a solution.

How can I do this?

Comment: while this question is about a particular code analysis tool it still is solely about systems administration and software troubleshooting ... please ask these kinds of questions on superuser.com

Comment: What about deactivate the rule you don't want and implement you own specific one?

Comment: @specializt It is indeed a question about a code analysis tool, in particular how to change its behavior in relation to fxml code. I wouldn't call that systems administration or software troubleshooting any more than questions about configuring ant or maven.  Can you please substantiate your comment with a reference to the particular section of the SO help center?  Furthermore, the help center of SU also has a list of subjects that are considered off-topic there.  First item in that list is *programming and software development*. How do you think users of superuser will receive this question?

Comment: most of them will receive it like any other question - just because your question is about a programming **tool** it doesnt have to be about **programming**, correlation does not imply causation.

Comment: @specializt [help/on-topic] : Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow *unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.*. Findbugs is only used for programming.  SU helpcenter: *software development* is off-topic.  This question is about software development.  There are your "causations".  There's not 1 question about findbugs on SU, while 746 on SO are tagged "findbugs", and quite some of them are about configuring it.  Can you please substantiate your comments with a reference to the particular sections of the help centers?

Comment: @LoicM. Good hint, thanks.  I'll take a look at the implementation of the detector for unused private methods and see if I can find a useful pattern for `@FXML` annotated ones in the bytecode.  For anyone interested in the subject, there's a nice article about implementing custom detectors over at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-findbug2/